# What kind of future verb tense is this: "will needs continue"?

Tags: future-tense

What kind of future verb tense is this: "will needs continue"?

> These contests may take place at any time the competitors express
> their readiness, due notice of course, being given the day previous,
> for the benefit of the public. When once started, the gliding
> performances of a single contestant **will needs continue** several days,
> and plenty of entertainment is promised the public in this
> aero-department.

Source: [“ “Gliders” at the World’s Fair. An Extraordinary Official Contest. Most Remarkable of All Flying Devices Entered in Great Aeronautic Competition. ”, St. Louis Post-Dispatch, St. Louis, Missouri, July 24, 1904, Sunday Magazine, col. 1-6, p. 4.](https://www.newspapers.com/clip/13457613/st-louis-post-dispatch/) (**see col. 6, the last paragraph**.)

Comment: I wouldn't know what "part of speech" to call it, but in the cited context, I don't think ***needs*** is a verb at all. It's a highly stylised / dated / poetic usage equivalent to *...will **of necessity** continue...* And quite apart from the fact that the usage isn't all that common anyway, almost every other writer would use [***must** needs continue*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+needs+continue%2Cmust+needs+continue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20needs%20continue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20needs%20continue%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The usage was also covered much more extensively on our sister site ELU, before ELL was even set up. See [***Explanation of “must needs”.***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34788/explanation-of-must-needs)